# Writing a C++ wrapper for a C library

Tags: c++, c, wrapper

I have a legacy C library, written in an OO type form. Typical functions are like:

```
LIB *lib_new();
void lib_free(LIB *lib);
int lib_add_option(LIB *lib, int flags);
void lib_change_name(LIB *lib, char *name);
```

I'd like to use this library in my C++ program, so I'm thinking a C++ wrapper is required.
The above would all seem to map to something like:

```
class LIB
{
    public:
         LIB();
         ~LIB();
         int add_option(int flags);
         void change_name(char *name);
...
};
```

I've never written a C++ wrapper round C before, and can't find much advice about it. Is this a good/typical/sensible approach to creating a C++/C wrapper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A C++ wrapper is not required - you can simply call the C functions from your C++ code. IMHO, it's best not to wrap C code - if you want to turn it into C++ code - fine, but do a complete re-write.

Practically, assuming your C functions are declared in a file called myfuncs.h then in your C++ code you will want to include them like this:

```
extern "C" {
   #include "myfuncs.h"
}
```

in order to give them C linkage when compiled with the C++ compiler.

Comment: I disagree (but no downvote). For simple C libs, a wrapper is often unnecessary. However, for more complicated C libs, a lightweight C wrapper can be invaluable. One example springs to mind: Tibco has a very lightweight wrapper around Tibrv which is immensely helpful.

Comment: @Nathan In some ways. MFC is a lightweight wrapper for the C Windows API. Whether it has added to the happiness of mankind is another issue :-)

Comment: I agree with Nathan - wrapping C libraries of some complexity, especially third-party ones, often makes them more useful to C++ clients. It also enables one to implement features on top of those provided by the C library (caching comes to mind).

Comment: @Bojan Cool! Post answer here explaining to the OP how to do it!

Comment: One major reason to wrap C functions is so that you can throw exceptions when errors arise.

Comment: @Winston Wrapping C code to use exceptions is almost impossible, in my experience. But if you've done it, please explain how.

Comment: Good C headers should generally do the extern "C" thing internally when compiled as C++.

Comment: WFC is a lightweight wrapper around the Windows API.  MFC varies from lightweight to quite heavyweight indeed depending on which part you are talking about (for example message maps).

Comment: Wouldn't the C++ provide the advantage that the `lib_free()` will be called by the destructor when the wrapper object goes out of scope?

Comment: @Neil In my experience, there aren't many "general" tips for wrapping C libraries. Throwing exceptions where C code returns errors is certainly doable. Exactly what is needed to accomplish that depends on the C library. Without support for exceptions, though, there isn't much point in wrapping.

Comment: @Bojan: Adding RAII for resources management around a C library seems very much worthy imho.

Comment: @Neil 

It seem straightforward enough to throw exceptions when a C library indicates that an error has occurred. Of course, if you are called from the C library then its trickier.

Comment: One major reason to wrap C functions with C++ classes is to enable unit testing.  See https://github.com/mlb5000/CFunctionWrapperGenerator for a way to generate these from C headers

Comment: @caf The wrapper class shouldn't have a destructor unless it's doing deep copies.

Answer (score 9):

I usually only write a simple RAII wrapper instead of wrapping each member function:

```
class Database: boost::noncopyable {
  public:
    Database(): handle(db_construct()) {
        if (!handle) throw std::runtime_error("...");
    }
    ~Database() { db_destruct(handle); }
    operator db_t*() { return handle; }
  private:
    db_t* handle;
};
```

With the type conversion operator this can be used with the C functions:

```
Database db;
db_access(db, ...);  // Calling a C function with db's type conversion operator
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it only makes sense to write a wrapper if it makes the use of the library simpler. In your case, you're making it unnecessary to pass a LIB* around, and presumably it will be possible to create LIB objects on the stack, so I'd say this is an improvement.

Comment: It's still necessary to pass LIB::LIB objects around. And allocating LIB::LIB objects on stack will give you only auto semantics, as probably new C LIB object will be allocated on heap in construction. But despite this, C++ wrapper is still handy.

Answer (score 2):

That's generally how I would approach it.  I would also not use char* but use std::string.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ wrapper is not needed per se. There's nothing stopping you from calling the C functions in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also look at renaming LIB to something a bit better, if nothing else  "Lib"

Change Name is likely to be a getter setter...

so   GetName(char *)  SetName(char *)

and then look at changing it to std::string instead of char*,  if  its SetName(const std::string name)  it will accept a char* as a parameter.

ie, slowly move to C++isms

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the C library's allocation/deallocation instances are **create_instance** and **destroy_instance**, and it exposes a function called **call_function**, and it does not provide an API for deep copying instances, this will work:

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(): m_instance(create_instance(), destroy_instance) {}

    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        // null check
        return bool(m_instance);
    }

    void callFunction()
    {
        call_function(m_instance.get());
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<instance, decltype(&destroy_instance)> m_instance;
};
```